# What's the earliest point I can get the queried object ID?

Tags: plugin-development, themes, hooks, actions, mobile

I'm writing a supplement plugin to [Wordpress Mobile Pack](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mobile-pack/) because I would like to use the default theme on pages that are assigned a certain page template. My plugin will only deal with the mobile switcher portion of that plugin, so the other components can be ignored (I think).

Looking at the source for `wpmp_switcher.php`, all the `add_action` and `add_filter` calls of relevance are not in a function -- they are executed when the file is included as so:

```
add_action('init', 'wpmp_switcher_init');
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpmp_switcher_admin_menu');
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpmp_switcher_wp_footer');
add_filter('stylesheet', 'wpmp_switcher_stylesheet');
add_filter('template', 'wpmp_switcher_template');
add_filter('option_home', 'wpmp_switcher_option_home_siteurl');
add_filter('option_siteurl', 'wpmp_switcher_option_home_siteurl');
```

I have removed the actions/filters associated with what make the WPMP plugin tick by using the `plugins_loaded` hook:

```
function remove_all_wpmp_switchers() {
  remove_action('init', 'wpmp_switcher_init');
  remove_action('admin_menu', 'wpmp_switcher_admin_menu');
  remove_action('wp_footer', 'wpmp_switcher_wp_footer');
  remove_filter('stylesheet', 'wpmp_switcher_stylesheet');
  remove_filter('template', 'wpmp_switcher_template');
  remove_filter('option_home', 'wpmp_switcher_option_home_siteurl');
  remove_filter('option_siteurl', 'wpmp_switcher_option_home_siteurl');
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'remove_all_wpmp_switchers');
```

So far, so good.

Now I would like to use the following code to add back the actions/filters when my template is not being used:

```
function wpmp_switcher_exclusions_init(WP_Query $wp_query) {
  $template_file_name = get_post_meta($wp_query->get_queried_object_id(),
                                      '_wp_page_template', true);
  if ($template_file_name != 'my-responsive-template.php') {
    wpmp_switcher_init();
    add_action('admin_menu', 'wpmp_switcher_admin_menu');
    add_action('wp_footer', 'wpmp_switcher_wp_footer');
    add_filter('stylesheet', 'wpmp_switcher_stylesheet');
    add_filter('template', 'wpmp_switcher_template');
    add_filter('option_home', 'wpmp_switcher_option_home_siteurl');
    add_filter('option_siteurl', 'wpmp_switcher_option_home_siteurl');
  }
}
add_action('parse_query', 'wpmp_switcher_exclusions_init');
```

The problem is that, even as early as the `parse_query` hook is, the `wpmp_switcher_init` function is called too late. The `functions.php` files for both the desktop and mobile templates attempt to load, causing fatal errors due to re-defined functions.

If the template can be retrieved earlier than this, I'm not sure how to do it. It looks like I need to somehow run my code using the `setup_theme` hook. If I can figure out how to do this, I will likely only need the one function in my plugin since `setup_theme` is called before `init`.

Any help with this is VERY appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more compact and WordPress-ish way, using [`url_to_postid()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid):

```
function wpmp_switcher_exclusions_init() {
  $pid = url_to_postid( home_url( add_query_arg( array() ) ) );
  if (
    (int) $pid > 0 &&
    get_post_meta( $pid, '_wp_page_template', TRUE ) === 'my-responsive-template.php'
   ) {
    remove_action('init', 'wpmp_switcher_init');
    remove_action('admin_menu', 'wpmp_switcher_admin_menu');
    remove_action('wp_footer', 'wpmp_switcher_wp_footer');
    remove_filter('stylesheet', 'wpmp_switcher_stylesheet');
    remove_filter('template', 'wpmp_switcher_template');
    remove_filter('option_home', 'wpmp_switcher_option_home_siteurl');
    remove_filter('option_siteurl', 'wpmp_switcher_option_home_siteurl');
  }
}

add_action( 'setup_theme', 'wpmp_switcher_exclusions_init' );
```

Comment: Nice! This absolutely saves a few lines and handles stuff I would forget like leading/trailing slash issues!

Answer (score 1):

I found the [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969949/if-has-term-load-other-wordpress-theme) (how about that?). Basically, my code looks like this now:

```
function wpmp_switcher_exclusions_init() {
  // Try to get post slug from the URL since the global $post object isn't available this early
  $post = get_page_by_path($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], OBJECT, 'page' );
  if (!$post) $post = get_page_by_path(untrailingslashit($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), OBJECT, 'page' );
  if (!$post) $post = get_page_by_path(substr(untrailingslashit($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),1), OBJECT, 'page' );
  if (!$post) return;

  $template_file_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
  if ($template_file_name == 'my-responsive-template.php') {
    remove_action('init', 'wpmp_switcher_init');
    remove_action('admin_menu', 'wpmp_switcher_admin_menu');
    remove_action('wp_footer', 'wpmp_switcher_wp_footer');
    remove_filter('stylesheet', 'wpmp_switcher_stylesheet');
    remove_filter('template', 'wpmp_switcher_template');
    remove_filter('option_home', 'wpmp_switcher_option_home_siteurl');
    remove_filter('option_siteurl', 'wpmp_switcher_option_home_siteurl');
  }
}
add_action('setup_theme', 'wpmp_switcher_exclusions_init');
```

Hope this helps someone else!